# Troubleshooting "Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent"

Tags: php, session

i am getting    **Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at**  error

If i submit form data to a different file for processing, it works. But if i submit form data to the same page, it gives this error.

please suggst

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Welcome</title>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 

    $('#nav li').hover(
        function () {
            //show its submenu
            $('ul', this).slideDown(100);

        }, 
        function () {
            //hide its submenu
            $('ul', this).slideUp(100);         
        }
    );

});
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="header">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="menu"><table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="80%">
    <tr>
    <td>

    <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Catalog</a>
    <ul><li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bulk Upload</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </li>


    <li><a href="#">Purchase  </a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Customer Service</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CS Panel</a></li>

    </ul>           
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">All Reports</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Configuration</a>
    <ul> <li><a href="#">Look and Feel </a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Business Details</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CS Details</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Emaqil Template</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Domain and Analytics</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Courier</a></li>
         </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Accounts</a>
    <ul><li><a href="#">Ledgers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Account Details</a></li>
        </ul>
         <div class="clear"></div></li>

</ul></td></tr></table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><table width="80%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
          <tr>
            <td width="22%" height="327" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="45"><strong>-&gt; Products</strong></td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="61"><strong>-&gt; Categories</strong></td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="48"><strong>-&gt; Sub Categories</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
            <td width="78%" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="26%">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td width="74%"><h2>Manage Categories</h2></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="30">&nbsp;

                </td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>


</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>
                <table width="49%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr><td>




<?php


                if (isset($_SESSION['error']))

                {

                    echo "<span id=\"error\"><p>" . $_SESSION['error'] . "</p></span>";

                    unset($_SESSION['error']);

                }

                ?>

                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <p>
                 <label class="style4">Category Name</label>

                   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="categoryname" /><br /><br />

                    <label class="style4">Category Image</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <input type="file" name="image" /><br />

                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />

                   <br />
<br />
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="UPLOAD" />

                </p>

                </form>




                             <?php

session_start();

require("includes/conn.php");


function is_valid_type($file)

{

    $valid_types = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/bmp", "image/gif", "image/png");



    if (in_array($file['type'], $valid_types))

        return 1;

    return 0;
}

function showContents($array)

{

    echo "<pre>";

    print_r($array);

    echo "</pre>";
}


$TARGET_PATH = "images/category";

$cname = $_POST['categoryname'];

$image = $_FILES['image'];

$cname = mysql_real_escape_string($cname);

$image['name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($image['name']);

$TARGET_PATH .= $image['name'];

if ( $cname == "" || $image['name'] == "" )

{

    $_SESSION['error'] = "All fields are required";

    header("Location: managecategories.php");

    exit;

}

if (!is_valid_type($image))

{

    $_SESSION['error'] = "You must upload a jpeg, gif, or bmp";

    header("Location: managecategories.php");

    exit;

}




if (file_exists($TARGET_PATH))

{

    $_SESSION['error'] = "A file with that name already exists";

    header("Location: managecategories.php");

    exit;

}


if (move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $TARGET_PATH))

{



    $sql = "insert into Categories (CategoryName, FileName) values ('$cname', '" . $image['name'] . "')";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not insert data into DB: " . mysql_error());

  header("Location: mangaecategories.php");

    exit;

}

else

{





    $_SESSION['error'] = "Could not upload file.  Check read/write persmissions on the directory";

    header("Location: mangagecategories.php");

    exit;

}

?>
```

Here is the code for Display

```
<?php  
                  require("includes/conn.php"); 



                $sql = "select CategoryID, CategoryName, FileName, Status from Categories";

                $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not access DB: " . mysql_error());



                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

                {

                     echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='10'>";


                                        echo "<tr><td>  </td><td>Category ID</td><td>Category Name</td><td>Status</td><td>Edit</td><td>Delete</td></tr>";

                                        echo "<tr><td> <img src=\"images/" . $row['FileName'] . "\" alt=\"\" /> </td>";
                                        echo "<td>". $row['CategoryID'] . "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>". $row['CategoryName'] . "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>". $row['Status']. "</td>";
                                            echo "<td> <a href= 'edit.php?CategoryID=" .$row['id']. "'> Edit </a></td>";
                                            echo "<td> <a href= 'delete.php?CategoryID=" .$row['id']. "'> Edit </a></td>";
                                         echo "</tr> </table>";

                }



            ?>
```

Nothing is happening here. Please suggest

Comment: There should not be any echo before session start. Basically there should not be any output character produced/printed before changing headers or session start. So, If you have echo. Or if you have blank space after php tag (or html or any output) in your include files then this error will come.

Comment: Rahul bhai, `session_start();` should be ur first line of php page to avoid this types of errors. Be advise all your php code for processing the form data should be in top

Comment: In my case I had to set the file encoding without BOM.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You will find I have added the session_start() at the very top of the page. I have also removed the session_start() call later in the page. This page should work fine.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Welcome</title>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 

    $('#nav li').hover(
        function () {
            //show its submenu
            $('ul', this).slideDown(100);

        }, 
        function () {
            //hide its submenu
            $('ul', this).slideUp(100);         
        }
    );

});
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="header">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="menu"><table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="80%">
    <tr>
    <td>

    <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Catalog</a>
    <ul><li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bulk Upload</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        </li>


    <li><a href="#">Purchase  </a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Customer Service</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CS Panel</a></li>

    </ul>           
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">All Reports</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Configuration</a>
    <ul> <li><a href="#">Look and Feel </a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Business Details</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">CS Details</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Emaqil Template</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Domain and Analytics</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Courier</a></li>
         </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Accounts</a>
    <ul><li><a href="#">Ledgers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Account Details</a></li>
        </ul>
         <div class="clear"></div></li>

</ul></td></tr></table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><table width="80%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
          <tr>
            <td width="22%" height="327" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="45"><strong>-&gt; Products</strong></td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="61"><strong>-&gt; Categories</strong></td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="48"><strong>-&gt; Sub Categories</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
            <td width="78%" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                      <td width="26%">&nbsp;</td>
                      <td width="74%"><h2>Manage Categories</h2></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="30">&nbsp;

                </td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>


</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>
                <table width="49%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr><td>




<?php


                if (isset($_SESSION['error']))

                {

                    echo "<span id=\"error\"><p>" . $_SESSION['error'] . "</p></span>";

                    unset($_SESSION['error']);

                }

                ?>

                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <p>
                 <label class="style4">Category Name</label>

                   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="categoryname" /><br /><br />

                    <label class="style4">Category Image</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <input type="file" name="image" /><br />

                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />

                   <br />
<br />
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="UPLOAD" />

                </p>

                </form>




                             <?php


require("includes/conn.php");


function is_valid_type($file)

{

    $valid_types = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/bmp", "image/gif", "image/png");



    if (in_array($file['type'], $valid_types))

        return 1;

    return 0;
}

function showContents($array)

{

    echo "<pre>";

    print_r($array);

    echo "</pre>";
}


$TARGET_PATH = "images/category";

$cname = $_POST['categoryname'];

$image = $_FILES['image'];

$cname = mysql_real_escape_string($cname);

$image['name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($image['name']);

$TARGET_PATH .= $image['name'];

if ( $cname == "" || $image['name'] == "" )

{

    $_SESSION['error'] = "All fields are required";

    header("Location: managecategories.php");

    exit;

}

if (!is_valid_type($image))

{

    $_SESSION['error'] = "You must upload a jpeg, gif, or bmp";

    header("Location: managecategories.php");

    exit;

}




if (file_exists($TARGET_PATH))

{

    $_SESSION['error'] = "A file with that name already exists";

    header("Location: managecategories.php");

    exit;

}


if (move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $TARGET_PATH))

{



    $sql = "insert into Categories (CategoryName, FileName) values ('$cname', '" . $image['name'] . "')";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not insert data into DB: " . mysql_error());

  header("Location: mangaecategories.php");

    exit;

}

else

{





    $_SESSION['error'] = "Could not upload file.  Check read/write persmissions on the directory";

    header("Location: mangagecategories.php");

    exit;

}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, But Still it gives same error in 
if (file_exists($TARGET_PATH))

{

    $_SESSION['error'] = "A file with that name already exists";

    header("Location: managecategories.php");

    exit;

} and by default A file with that name already exists message displays

Comment: I find you are not checking if the form has been submitted or is being loaded the first time. Hence, you code to prepare the image file name in $TARGET_PATH is always executing - when normally page loads the first time or when the page is posted. You can check if the page is being posted or loading first time by checking: if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { /* place your code here */ }

Comment: Hi, Got resolved. As you suggested error was because for repeated header redirection. I removed the redirect header statement and it worked.. Thanks you very much

Comment: Please suggest me how to display the image along with the other images in the database in the same page

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue, but my solution wasn't as obvious as the suggested ones. It turned out that my php-file was written in UTF-8, which caused issues. I copy/pasted the content of the entire file into a new php-file (Notepad++ tells me this is written in ANSI rather than UTF-8), and now it work flawlessly.

Comment: I had the encoding set as UTF-8 (which was correct... database connection is set to UTF-8 for use with SVG) but stopped PHP sessions working

Comment: @JulianB: Make sure the encoding is set to "UTF-8 without BOM".

Comment: Thank god. Didn't realize this thing can happen with switching of text editors. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For me even copy past didn't work, it was not my project, but I had nightmare fixing it issue, I don't know how the `invisible` `UTF-8` got there, all text editors on `Linux` still copying if, so I create new `ISO-8859` empty file and copy past line by line, the issue were on the `first line` I rewrite it and past the rest of the file and it's works.

Answer (score 10):

The answer is above by Ross.

Firstly, putting session_start() as the first line of code will mean that you cannot deserialise any objects correctly into session variables.

The reason for getting this issue is 99% likely to be trailing spaces at the end of your include files (yes - I know it sounds unlikely but just try it).  The offending file is in the error message.  I wanted to back up Ross answer which worked for me but this site is counter intuitive.

IGNORE the nonsense answers.  Remove the trailing spaces, newlines etc... and all will be well.  ROSS knows what he is talking about.
Putting session_start() at the top of your file DOES work but it isnt the correct solution.

Comment: Just remove the closing `?>` entirely and this will never happen. It is not needed and not recommended

Comment: Wow thanks. never noted this simple mistake happen from me... thank you very much

Answer (score 6):

replace `session_start();` with `@session_start();` in your code

Comment: This is an ok solution. However, this just ignoring the warning rather than fixing it.

Answer (score 5):

This should solve your problem. session_start() should be called before any character is sent back to the browser. In your case, HTML and blank lines were sent before you called session_start(). [Documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).

To further explain your question of why it works when you submit to a different page, that page either do not use session_start() or calls session_start() before sending any character back to the client! This page on the other hand was calling session_start() much later when a lot of HTML has been sent back to the client (browser).

The better way to code is to have a common header file that calls connects to MySQL database, calls session_start() and does other common things for all pages and include that file on top of each page like below:

```
include "header.php";
```

This will stop issues like you are having as also allow you to have a common set of code to manage across a project. Something definitely for you to think about I would suggest after looking at your code.

```
<?php
session_start();

                if (isset($_SESSION['error']))

                {

                    echo "<span id=\"error\"><p>" . $_SESSION['error'] . "</p></span>";

                    unset($_SESSION['error']);

                }

                ?>

                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <p>
                 <label class="style4">Category Name</label>

                   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="categoryname" /><br /><br />

                    <label class="style4">Category Image</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <input type="file" name="image" /><br />

                    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />

                   <br />
<br />
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="UPLOAD" />

                </p>

                </form>




                             <?php



require("includes/conn.php");


function is_valid_type($file)

{

    $valid_types = array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/bmp", "image/gif", "image/png");



    if (in_array($file['type'], $valid_types))

        return 1;

    return 0;
}

function showContents($array)

{

    echo "<pre>";

    print_r($array);

    echo "</pre>";
}


$TARGET_PATH = "images/category";

$cname = $_POST['categoryname'];

$image = $_FILES['image'];

$cname = mysql_real_escape_string($cname);

$image['name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($image['name']);

$TARGET_PATH .= $image['name'];

if ( $cname == "" || $image['name'] == "" )

{

    $_SESSION['error'] = "All fields are required";

    header("Location: managecategories.php");

    exit;

}

if (!is_valid_type($image))

{

    $_SESSION['error'] = "You must upload a jpeg, gif, or bmp";

    header("Location: managecategories.php");

    exit;

}




if (file_exists($TARGET_PATH))

{

    $_SESSION['error'] = "A file with that name already exists";

    header("Location: managecategories.php");

    exit;

}


if (move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], $TARGET_PATH))

{



    $sql = "insert into Categories (CategoryName, FileName) values ('$cname', '" . $image['name'] . "')";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not insert data into DB: " . mysql_error());

  header("Location: mangaecategories.php");

    exit;

}

else

{





    $_SESSION['error'] = "Could not upload file.  Check read/write persmissions on the directory";

    header("Location: mangagecategories.php");

    exit;

}

?>
```

Comment: Before the form starts i have some 40 lines of html code. should i use session_data() at the beginning? Because even after using the session_start before isset i am getting the same error.. I have edited the code with html. plz have a look

Comment: If i use it in the line 1, still i get the same error. And also i get A file with that name already exists, message without any logic

Answer (score 4):

use     `ob_start();` before  `session_start();` at top of your page like this

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
```

Comment: Will need to call ob_end_flush() at the end of the page too. [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

Comment: Thanks, But Still it gives same error in if (file_exists($TARGET_PATH)) { $_SESSION['error'] = "A file with that name already exists"; header("Location: managecategories.php"); exit; } and by default A file with that name already exists message displays

Comment: if i use ob_start(); and ob_end_flush(), the file doesnt open but it displays "too many redirects occured while opening.."

Answer (score 4):

For others who may run across this - it can also occur if someone carelessly leaves trailing spaces from a php include file.  Example:

```
 <?php 
    require_once('mylib.php');
    session_start();
 ?>
```

In the case above, if the mylib.php has blank spaces after its closing ?> tag, this will cause an error.  This obviously can get annoying if you've included/required many files.  Luckily the error tells you which file is offending.

HTH

Answer (score 4):

Generally this error arise when we send header after echoing or printing. If this error arise on a specific page then make sure that page is not echoing anything before calling to start_session().

Example of Unpredictable Error:

```
 <?php //a white-space before <?php also send for output and arise error
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();

//your page content
```

One more example:

```
<?php
includes 'functions.php';
?> <!-- This new line will also arise error -->
<?php
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();

//your page content
```

Conclusion: Do not output any character before calling session_start() or header() functions not even a white-space or new-line

Comment: This happened to me with MS Code formatting leading spaces for my php code. It worked fine on my home DEV system, but when I put in on my hosted site, I got the errors.

Answer (score 4):

Just replace session_start with this.

```
if (!session_id() && !headers_sent()) {
   session_start();
}
```

You can put it anywhere, even at the end :)
Works fine for me. $_SESSION is accessible as well.

Answer (score 3):

use `session_start()` at the top of the page.

for more details please read the link [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve similar `Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent` by just removing a space in front of the `<?php` tag.

It worked.

Comment: This happened for me too and I wrestled with the bug for days. All I had to do was remove the space before the <?php tag.

Answer (score 2):

I had a website transferring from one host to another, it seemed to work fine on the old host but a few pages on the new host threw the error

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent
```

while I always kept the

```
 <?php
session_start();
```

at the top of the page no spaces and nothing inserted before

it really bugged me that I stared every page with the session opening, and it worked on some pages and run through a bug on others
I picked the pages that had the problems, backed them up, created new blank pages and simply copied and pasted the code as is, saved and uploaded and boom, problem gone!

this is something you guys may need to consider, it may have been the encoding of the page, or something, not sure the exact source of the problem, but here is a fix to look at in case you guys run into a similar problem

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to set the file encoding without BOM.

Answer (score 0):

This started for me when I redirected my site to https:// (for SSL Certificate). From my experience with this issue, the `session_start()` had to be before the browser saw any HTML code. For my example, I was using `session_start()` in nav.php to determine the options of the navigation bar. I ended up placing `session_start()` right after the php comments in the index.php file and every page which called nav.php. I was able to keep the php comments before `session_start()` but could not keep the HTML comments above the php.

Answer (score 0):

Check any extra space before php tag.