# How to add new elements to a $_SESSION array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session, shopping-cart

I am building a shopping cart and in my task I have to print out the items that the customer bought. I have tried to store the items in an array `$_SESSION['items']` but no success. I have tried this:

```
$_SESSION['items'][] = $item;
```

but it did not work.

Please give some advice?

Comment: That's all you need. How is this "not working"? The array never gets created? Are you using session_start() properly everywhere you're modifying $_SESSION?

Comment: You probably only have to do session_start() at the beginning of your page and life will be good

Comment: Make sure your `session_start` appears before any HTML, otherwise it won't work. Ensure your warnings are enabled so you can see any problems with session initialisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)? You need to declare `session_start()` before you use `$_SESSION` in order to save values inside a session variable.

Also you are using a session array, so use `print_r($_SESSION['items'])` to see what it outputs, inorder to access the array value you need to specify the index too, for example

```
echo $_SESSION['items'][0]
```

Comment: @DilshatAbduwalli use this and see what you get `print_r($_SESSION['items'])`

Comment: why does every one incorrectly say "top of the page"  for session_start?

Comment: before usage, is not the top of the page, line 50 million is fine if you done use sessions until 50 million and 1

Comment: when i use print_r($_SESSION['items']) is is printing Arry [0] => [1] => [1] ..)

Comment: @DilshatAbduwalli Ya so if you want to echo out the particular value, use that particular index number/name, read my edited answer

Comment: @Dagon You are wrong here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612163/troubleshooting-warning-session-start-cannot-send-session-cache-limiter-h

Comment: @DilshatAbduwalli `$item` is empty

Comment: @Dagon Ok it won't hurt anyone if we place at the top of the page, I'll stick to my standards :)

Comment: if your ok being worng, its ok with me :-)

Answer (score 1):

use `session_start();` to declare session.
and use `$_SESSION['items'][] = $item;`

Should work..

Comment: actully @MarcB that only applies to cookie-based sessions

Comment: @MarcB Ya please make him understand, that what harms if we put `session_start()` at the top of the page

Comment: @dagon: it can harm trans-sid sessions as well, if you turn on the session AFTER you've already output some/all forms and/or links on the page. PHP will not reach back in time to rewrite perviously performed output with the trans_sid

Comment: well that applies to any variable you can't use it before it exists, nothing 'special' there.

Answer (score 1):

for using session variables you have to start session using `session_start();` 
to add elements try `$_SESSION['items'][]=$items;` and to print session variable try `print_r($_SESSION['items'][]);`
or

```
foreach ($_SESSION['items'][] as $item)
{
       echo $item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['req_id_in_sess'] = array();

$_SESSION['req_id_in_sess'] = $req_id; //$req_id is array 



 foreach($_SESSION["req_id_in_sess"] as $key => $val)
    { 

        echo $val,"<br/>";
    }

//for single output 

echo  $_SESSION["req_id_in_sess"][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was augmenting some existing base `$_SESSION` variable.

For example, I was initially just setting:

```
$_SESSION['amount'] = 4300
```

Then I tried to add a display 'sub-variable':

```
$_SESSION['amount']['Display'] = $4,300.00.
```

But I found that the second operation overwrote part of the base variable.

The fix was to do things explicitly:

```
$_SESSION['amount']['Amount'] = 4300;
$_SESSION['amount']['Display'] = $4,300.00
```