# PHP redirect after session start unsuccessful

Tags: php, mysql

I am managing to initiate a session after 'checklogin.php' executes but when I try to redirect to 'login_success.php' I remain on the same 'checklogin.php' page. Do you have any suggestions for what I can do?

```
<?php

    ob_start();
    $host="";
    $username="";
    $password="";
    $db_name="";
    $tbl_name="";

    // Connect to server and select databse.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    // username and password sent from form 
    $myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
    $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count==1){

    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['myusername']=$myusername;
    $_SESSION['mypassword']=$mypassword;
    header("location:login_success.php");
    }
    else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password. Please try again.";
    }
    ob_end_flush();

    ?>
```

I get the following errors:

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /homepages/46/d473160420/htdocs/checklogin.php:58) in /homepages/46/d473160420/htdocs/checklogin.php on line 93

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/46/d473160420/htdocs/checklogin.php:58) in /homepages/46/d473160420/htdocs/checklogin.php on line 96
```

Comment: why are you controlling the buffer output here?

Comment: Where would you suggest I control it?

Comment: I'm just wondering **why** you are controlling it

Comment: `ob_start()` is used to control output buffer in php console scripts. You don't need that on your website.

Comment: judging by those errors you've just posted up, your problem is that output to the browser has already been sent where you are trying to call `session_start()` - it's probably a database query failing. To find out, put a big fat `exit();` call just before `session_start();` and you should see a nice descriptive error for you to fix up

Comment: possible duplicate of [Troubleshooting "Warning: session\_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612163/troubleshooting-warning-session-start-cannot-send-session-cache-limiter-h)

Comment: check if there is any newline before PHP start tag

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['myusername']) AND isset($_POST['mypassword']))
{
$host="";
$username="";
$password="";
$db_name="";
$tbl_name="";

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_SESSION['myusername']= $myusername;
$_SESSION['mypassword']= $mypassword;
header("Location: login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password. Please try again.";
}
}else{
echo "Type your Username and Password";
}
?>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. The first code I've posted was wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I've used this version.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered that I had placed the php code within the HTML. I placed it at the top of the document and now it works.