# session cache error only on two pages - All other pages are working fine

Tags: php, session, config, session-variables

I developed a website from a developer. My website was working fine. All of a sudden I discovered that whenever I click on Contact Us link, I get an error

> "Warning: session_start() Cannot send session cache limiter - heards
>   already sent (output started at /home/xxx/public_html/contact.php:1)
>   in /home/xxx/public_html/connection/config.php on line 2"

This was not happenning before. The developer is not giving me support and is ignoring my emails. So I searched and researched for it a lot on the Internet and found that there is something wrong in the way session_start() is defined.

**Here is the code of contact.php**

```
<?php
  include("connection/config.php");
  session_start();
?>
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['enquiry2']))
  {
    .
    .
    .
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
.
.
.
  <?php include "footer.php"; ?>
</html>
```

**Code of config.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
error_reporting(0);

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'localhost' || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == '192.168.1.111')
  {
    $con=
    .
    .
    }
  else
    {
      $con=
      .
      .
    }
error_reporting(E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING ^ E_ALL);
require_once("logic/class.config.php");
.
.
<?php date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");?>
```

In lot of articles I read that session_start() should be right at the top of the page so I reversed the second and third line of contact.php but it gave me same error pointing to contact.php file.

> "Warning: session_start() Cannot send session cache limiter - heards
>   already sent (output started at /home/xxx/public_html/contact.php:1)
>   in /home/xxx/public_html/connection/contact.php on line 2"

Earlier it was pointing to config.php fle

Same thing is happening in registration page. I have three files register.php, register1.php and register2.php. The same error occurs only on register3.php when it loads the page and once again when submit button is clicked.

I request if someone can help me identify the problem.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

*As suggested by Premalatha:*

Removed `session_start();` from contact.php -> but same warning.

Placed `session_start();` on top of `include("connection/config.php");` -> but same warning.

*As suggested by Alok:*

I dont know how to check if I am sending content or calling header somewhere before `session_start()`. The `session_start()` line is either on top or in the second line with first line being `include("connection/config.php");` that I tried interchanging upside down with no help.

One thing I fail to understand that other .php files also have the same coding then why this warning comes only on contact.php? Similarly, register1.php, register2.php also have same coding but why the warning comes only while loading and unloading register3.php. All was working before, this started all of a sudden and I dont remember doing any changes in any of these files so the issue may be something else. I also wanted to try suggestion from wangpeng but I could not find the php.ini file anywhere in cpanel. Moreover, I did not figure out how to check if the file's code if it is UTF8-BOM. Also where exactly should i put `OB_START()` because i am unable to identify where is the header.

**EDIT2**

By the way, this warning does not affect the functioning of the site. The error just appears and then disappears. However, it disturbs the css, all fonts and images become bigger and the look of the page goes for a toss. Can someone tell me how to ignore this error so that the system doesn't show it at all?

Comment: First, a warning is not the same as an error. Second, if you are already calling `session_start()` in the config.php, there is no need to call it again.

Comment: I will try removing session_start() in one of the file one by one and see what happens. Thanks. But still I am wondering why it happens only in two files, the coding is same for all files. Nevertheless, I will try and get back.

Comment: doesn't work :( I have edited my question with more details

Comment: By the way, this warning does not affect the functioning of the site. The error just appears and then disappears. However, it disturbs the css, all fonts and images become bigger and the look of the page goes for a toss. Can you tell me how to ignore this error so that the system doesn't show it at all?

Comment: Use `error_reporting(E_ERROR);` and remove all other `error_reporting()` functions in `config.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never thought the solution would be this !

However, when I read same thing from four different people, I had to try this and it worked ! I had few leading, trailing and blank spaces in my include files. I got rid of them and my problem was solved.

Here is the article that helped me a lot
[Troubleshooting "Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612163/troubleshooting-warning-session-start-cannot-send-session-cache-limiter-h)

if you have blank space after php tag (or html or any output) in your include files then this error will come. **-by Imdad**

The reason for getting this issue is 99% likely to be trailing spaces at the end of your include files (yes - I know it sounds unlikely but just try it). Remove the trailing spaces, newlines etc... and all will be well. **-by Chris B**

a white-space before `<?php` also send for output and arise error. Conclusion: Do not output any character before calling session_start() or header() functions not even a white-space or new-line **-by Biswadeep Sarkar**

For others who may run across this - it can also occur if someone carelessly leaves trailing spaces from a php include file. Example:

```
   <?php 
    require_once('mylib.php');
    session_start();
 ?>
```

In the case above, if the mylib.php has blank spaces after its closing ?> tag, this will cause an error. This obviously can get annoying if you've included/required many files. Luckily the error tells you which file is offending. **-by Ross**

Answer (score 0):

**Headers already sent** means PHP script sent the headers to the server already, and it cannot be modified now.

Which means before `session_start()` your script must be sending content or calling `header` to the server and and after sending it script is calling **session_start()** function which tries to modify the headers.

Solution in your case is to check you're not sending content or calling `header` some where before `session_start()` in both the scripts.

---

**Update:**

Try this,

Locate all the ***.php** files pointed in **contact.php** and find `session_start();` in it.

Replace it with the following,

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

Above code will make sure that you don't start the session again if it is already being started.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Before the `session_start()` line the developer has included a file. thats it. I dont know if i am sending any content or calling any header as i am not technically savyy.

Comment: Looks like some other issue. I have edited my question with more details

Comment: Do you know which version of PHP you've on your server ? Check this by placing `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in file. Let me know the PHP version.

Comment: Thanks. PHP Version 5.4.45, Build Date Jun 23 2016 01:56:40, Configuration File (php.ini) Path /usr/local/lib. I am unable to locate this path, I could not find the usr folder in cpanel.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I searched all .php files in contact.php file and found 12 .php files out of which 6 files had session_start(); in it to which I replaced with the code you gave. contact.php and config.php also includes in those 6 files. But this did not solve the problem. :(

Comment: Still getting the same warning ?

Comment: Yes. same warning. i know its weird and its very frustrating. i cannot even locate the php.ini file anywhere the location /usr/local/lib given by your phpinfo() line does not exist in cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

session_start();
 is already included in config.php file.
You can remove in contact.php file and it would start working without any issues.

If you still face any issues then you can place session_start(); line of code in contact.php above the include statement.

Comment: I already tried placing it above and I mentioned that in my question too. I will try to remove it from contact.php and see what happens. But still I am wondering why it happens only in two files, the coding is same for all files. Nevertheless, I will try and get back.

Comment: Tried your solution but both the things doesnt work. I have edited my question with more details

Comment: As wangpeng said, try to use ob_start() and ob_flush();

ob_start() needs to be placed start of the code
ob_flush() at the end of the code.

Place <?php ob_start(); ?> at the top of the contact.php (first line)
Place <?php ob_flush(); ?> at the bottom of the contact.php

Comment: If that doesn't work, we need to work with php.ini settings to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

1.php.ini session.auto_start = 0  to  session.auto_start = 1 .
2.check the file's code  is  UTF8-BOM?  yes,UTF8-BOM  to  UTF8.
3.OB_START();before header

Comment: Looks like something which i have not even explored. Where in cpnale is this php.ini file located? I need some help to locate and identify the file so that I can see whats in there

Comment: I could not find the php.ini file anywhere in cpanel. Moreover, I did not figure out how to check if the file's code if it is UTF8-BOM. Also where exactly should i put OB_START() because i am unable to identify where is the header.

Comment: sorry i cannot send the file. if you need specific info, please let me know.

Comment: http://www.jb51.net/article/39547.htm       http://www.jb51.net/article/21136.htm