# Session not destroying when logging out of online website but works with offline website

Tags: php, session

I just finished creating a website that includes a login page. When the user attempts to log in, I check the username and password against the database. If they both match, I start a session and set the session variables 'id' and 'uid', like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers = ? OR emailUsers = ?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location: ../login.php?error=sqlerror");
            exit();
        }
        else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mailuid, $mailuid);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['pwdUsers']);
                if ($pwdCheck == false) {
                    header("Location: ../login.php?error=wrongpwd&mail=".$mailuid);
                    exit();
                }
                elseif($pwdCheck == true) {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['idUsers'];
                    $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['uidUsers'];

                    header("Location: ../login.php?login=success");
                    exit();
                }
                else {
                    header("Location: ../login.php?error=wrongpwd");
                    exit();
                }
            }
            else {
                header("Location: ../login.php?error=nouser&mail=".$mailuid);
                exit();
            }
        }
```

In my header.php file, which is linked within every php page using `include 'header.php';`, I have php code that displays either log in/sign up buttons (if `$_SESSION['id']` is not set) or a log out button (if `$_SESSION['id']` is set). I also started a session in the header.php page. This is what the code of header.php looks like:

```
session_start();

      if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {

          echo 
          "<div id='logout-form'>
            <form action='includes/logout.inc.php' method='post'>
              <button type='submit' name='logout-submit'>Log Out</button>
            </form>
          </div>";

      }

      else {

          echo 
          "<div id='header-form'>
            <form action='includes/login.inc.php' method='post'>
              <button type='submit' name='login-button-header'>Log In</button>
            </form>
            <button id='signup-button'><a href='signup.php' class='header-signup'>Sign Up</a></button>
          </div>";

      }

      if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {

          echo '<p class="greeting">Hello, <span class="greetingName">' . $_SESSION['uid'] . '</span></p>';

      } 

      date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
```

Using xampp, I am connected to an apache server offline. When clicking through my site, the sessions work for every page; if I log in, it registers that I've logged in on every page I go to, as it should. However, when I posted my website a few days ago, it had trouble knowing if I was logged in or out. My website URL is [writingboxco.com](https://www.writingboxco.com) if you would like to see what I'm about to talk about. When I log in, it seems to know that I am logged in on every web page; I know this because it provides the message "Hello, [username]" on every page, which only happens when `$_SESSION['id']` is set. However, when I click "Log Out" and go back to the home page, it still thinks that I'm logged on (because I probably am, but I don't know why). When the "Log Out" button is clicked, the script "logout.inc.php" runs. In this file, I unset and destroy the session variables, like so:

```
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = [];
header("Location: ../login.php");
```

Additionally, I only stay logged in on some pages of the website. Some of them register that I've logged out, while other don't. 
I'm not sure why I stay logged in after clicking the "Log Out" button, which should destroy the session variables. When my site is used offline, it works perfectly fine; when I log out, every page realizes it. However, when online, it doesn't work for every page. It only works for some (some pages stay logged in and some pages correctly log out). Additionally, when I try to log in with an alternate account, it signs me in, but on certain pages, the message "Hello [username]" still displays the username of the account I just logged out of instead of the account I just logged into. Any ideas on what the problem could be? Is it a problem with the failure to destroy the session variables? Could it be other code I should be looking at? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
I found that there is an error message stating `[28-Jan-2020 00:02:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home1/writipe3/public_html/searchUsers.php:1) in /home1/writipe3/public_html/header.php on line 5`
 on the `error_log` file. Any ideas why this would be happening?

Answer (score 1):

When you're destroying a session in PHP you're not actually deleting it. You're merely marking it for garbage collection. The physical deletion happens later. So in order to ensure the session is actually destroyed you must also delete the session cookie, which propagate the session id.

If you look at **Example #1** of the [`session_destory()`](http://php.net/session-destroy) documentation you'd see some sample code of how to go about doing this:

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
```

### Why is this behavior variable across platforms?

The reason you may  see differences in how this atually works out in practice is because different platforms can use different methods of garbage collection for cleaning up session data. For example, on most Windows systems this might actually happen instantly. Some Debian-based (Ubuntu) systems are known to use an asynchronous GC method that happens outside of PHP.

PHP, by default, implements this via a probablistic algorithm wherein each request made to PHP will, within a given probability (usually about 1% of the time) will trigger the GC cycle. So the clean up is non-deterministic in almost all cases.

Comment: thanks for the info. I implemented the code and it still worked on my site offline. However, online, I'm still having trouble. When I click "Log In", a message saying "You are logged in!" displays on my login.php page. But when I click through my site, it doesn't say that I'm logged in except on one single page that has the "Hello, [username]" message. Would I have to set a cookie on the "login.inc.php" page as well or something of that sort?

Comment: No, `session_start()` sets the cookie for you. It sounds like something else is happening there that is not evident from this code.

Comment: okay, I'll look into my other code to see if I can find the problem. One thing I did notice is that when I try echoing any text in my "header.php" page, nothing is output. For example, I tried using print_r($_SESSION); in "header.php" to see what was happening with the session variables after clicking "Log Out", but no session variables are shown. Same with when I echo "hello world". Do you know anything about common underlying problems that I could potentially have here?

Comment: Well, if you set `$_SESSION = []` in the log out script then sure, it would be expected that it's empty.

Comment: I get what you mean. What I meant by that is there should at least be "Array ()" echoed onto the page, but that's not there, either; nothing shows up. Same with echoing text.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you have a syntax error somewhere. Try checking your logs, or if you're in development maybe turn on `display_errors`. But you'll need to do it in your php.ini if it is a syntax error.

Comment: I looked into it and found that I was receiving an error message: [28-Jan-2020 00:02:56 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home1/writipe3/public_html/searchUsers.php:1) in /home1/writipe3/public_html/header.php on line 5. Does this offer any new possible solutions?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612163/troubleshooting-warning-session-start-cannot-send-session-cache-limiter-h