# Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent - Opencart Issue

Tags: opencart

I am getting the following error on our customers Opencart website after a recent website transfer from one server to another. Using opencart v1.5.6.4

Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/sites/10b/3/33a32a4f67/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_library_language.php:88) in /home/sites/10b/3/33a32a4f67/public_html/system/library/session.php on line 21Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/sites/10b/3/33a32a4f67/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_library_language.php:88) in /home/sites/10b/3/33a32a4f67/public_html/index.php on line 357

I believe this issue is preventing the site from functioning properly as currently having an issue with adding and taking away products from the cart.

Any ideas how to fix?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Troubleshooting "Warning: session\_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612163/troubleshooting-warning-session-start-cannot-send-session-cache-limiter-h)

Answer (score 0):

No idea what i did but i have fixed the issue. I simply deleted the vqmod folder and then reuploaded all other folders from the original server.